# ASP.NET 4.5 SQL Server 2012 deploy to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sql-server-2012

My problem is this error:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.*

Every time I open the website I deploy in IIS that's the error I get. This is my first time deploying ASP.NET 4.5 and SQL Server 2012. But when I'm using VS2010 ASP.NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 there's no problem.

I'm hoping you guys can help me thank you!

Comment: Have you at least tried what the error says? Ensuring that the server is up, accessible at the location your application is looking, configured to allow remote connections, and that the user you're using is valid with permissions?

Comment: When i'm running it in VS2012 it's okay but when I deploy it to IIS error comes!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't deployed while pointing to a local database?

Comment: I don't understand you @Neil :| sorry this is my first time using this VS2012 and SQL Server 2011

Comment: In your web.config file there will be a connection string setting. Whatever that is set to needs to accessible from the deployment target.

Comment: ohh that one I already did that. when i'm running the website in VS2012 it's okay.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2011** version - we had 2008, 2008 R2 and now 2012. Assuming you really mean the **2012** version, I update your post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
The server was not found or was not accessible
```

That error means the sql server is not at the requested ip address/port number.

```
    Verify that the instance name is correct and that 
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
```

The first thing you should do is attempt to connect to the sql server using SQL Management Studio.  If that fails then you need to figure out why.  Could be one of the following:

- a firewall issue; SQL Browser service isn't running;
- SQL Browser service is misconfigured;
- SQL Server isn't even installed where you are trying to deploy this;
- your site references a SQL server that isn't even accessible by it;
- your network card isn't plugged in....

If it works, then you need to update your project with the correct connection info.

Comment: i don't have sql server management because I reformat my laptop. I only install VS2012 with SQL SERVER 2011